# What are the Hodge and log Hodge groups of $M_{g,n}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, hodge-theory

I would like to know, ideally with a reference, what the Hodge and log Hodge numbers of the moduli space of stable curves $\bar M_{g, n}$ are. At the very least I'd like to know the genus zero case $g = 0$.

There are two natural sheaves on $\bar M_{g, n}$, the Kahler differentials $\Omega$ and the log Kahler differentials $\Omega({\rm log} D)$, where $D$ is the boundary divisor of singular curves. I would like to know the dimensions of the groups
$$
H^p(\bar M_{g, n}, \Omega^q) \quad \text{and} \quad H^p(\bar M_{g, n}, \Omega^q({\rm log} D)).
$$

If $g = 0$, I learned at a conference that Keel's results show all the cohomology is $(p, p)$ type and the map from Chow to homology is injective (and I think an isomorphism), so the answer is basically what Keel says for Chow groups. There is also a spectral sequence which gives the weights of the interior $M_{g, n}$. The weight pieces of $M_{g, n}$ are computed by the second groups $H^p(\bar M_{g, n}, \Omega^q({\rm log} D))$, so I feel like they should be known also.

Comment: I'm not an expert here; my apologies. I need the numbers for a computation I'm trying to do. I googled and read Dan Petersen's mathoverflow answers looking for an answer, but I could just be missing an obvious canonical reference. Thank you.

Comment: The groups $H^p(\bar M_{g,n}, \Omega^q(\log D))$ are the associated graded for *Hodge* filtration, the weight filtration is different. I imagine a determination would be out of reach, for now, once $g$ becomes moderately large.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the mistake. Is the g = 0 case doable?

Comment: If you are interested in the weight filtration, there are results on the top graded piece. See Tropical curves, graph complexes, and top weight cohomology of $\mathcal M_g$ https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10186 in which Chan, Galatius, and Payne obtain strong results on this part, including exponential lower bounds on the dimension, but the only known upper bounds are superexponential.

Comment: In genus $0$, for $\overline{\mathcal M}_{0,n}$ you've given the answer and for $\mathcal M_{0,n}$ I think the cohomology together with the Hodge structure can be computed directly from the iterated fibration structure and the associated sequence of spectral sequence: If I did this right the $i$'th Betti number is the coefficient of $x^i$ in $\prod_{j=2}^{n-2}( 1+jx)$ and this cohomology is entirely weight $2i$ and Hodge type $(i,i)$.

Comment: In genus 1, for $\mathcal M_{1,n}$, the discussion in 2.3.1 of Rational cohomology of the moduli spaces of pointed genus 1 curves
 https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5693 is relevant: Roughly, there is an algorithm to compute these but isn't (or wasn't 11 years ago?) a closed-form formula.

Comment: I agree with Will Sawin. For $\overline{M}_{1,n}$, I proved in https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1586 that the even cohomology is of $(p,p)$ type. This paper also contains some useful (?) stuff about the interior. The odd cohomology of $\overline M_{1,n}$ can be understood in terms of cusp forms for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf Z)$.

Comment: Very little can be said for arbitrary $g$ unless you fix the cohomological degree to be small (or large by duality). For $2k\leq 14$, $H^{2k}(\overline{M}_{g,n})$ is of type $(k,k)$ (https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.08830). The dimensions are not known. For odd degree $\leq 15$, there is a lot of vanishing known and some results about non-vanishing and dimension of various $h^{p,q}$ (https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.07759, https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.03113, https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.08830).